# how to convert this array to json （iOS）

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here is a array:

```
2011-1-1
2011-1-2
2011-3-3
2012-1-4
2012-1-5
2012-6-7
2012-6-9
2013-1-3
2013-1-8
2013-9-1
2013-9-2
2014-3-7
2014-3-13
2014-4-1
2014-4-17
```

I need convert this `NSDictionary` with nested `NSArray` to json like this（use objective-c）:

```
  {
        "y2011m1": [
            "2011-1-1",
            "2011-1-2"
        ],
        "y2011m3": [
            "2011-3-3"
        ],
        "y2012m1": [
            "2012-1-4",
            "2012-1-5"
        ],
        "y2012m6": [
            "2012-6-7",
            "2012-6-9"
        ],
        "y2013m1": [
            "2013-1-3",
            "2013-1-8"
        ],
        "y2013m9": [
            "2013-9-1",
            "2013-6-2"
        ],
        "y2014m3": [
            "2014-3-7",
            "2014-3-13"
        ],
        "y2014m4": [
            "2014-4-1",
            "2014-4-17"
        ]
    }
```

The same years and same month become "yxxxmx",and group by it，i don't know how to do （use objective-c），please help me ，thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: He seriously just joined the community. If you are going to down vote him/her, please let them know why so they can better contribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should convert array to NSDictionary first, and then use NSJSONSerialization method.

```
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: options: error:]
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: options: error:]

NSDictionary * toJson = @{@"y2001m1" : @[@"2011-1-1", @"2011-1-2"]};
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:toJson options:0 error:&error];
```

It will generate what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Code to con vert your input array to your dictionary format:

```
NSArray *datesArr = @[@"2011-1-1", @"2011-1-2", @"2011-3-3", @"2012-1-4", @"2012-1-5", @"2012-6-7", @"2012-6-9", @"2013-1-3", @"2013-1-8", @"2013-9-1", @"2013-9-2", @"2014-3-7", @"2014-3-13", @"2014-4-1", @"2014-4-17"];
for (NSString *date in datesArr) {
    NSArray *subStrArr = [date componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSString *ymStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"y%@m%@", [subStrArr objectAtIndex:0], [subStrArr objectAtIndex:1]];
    if ([jsonDict objectForKey:ymStr]) {
        NSMutableArray *ymStrJsonArray = [jsonDict objectForKey:ymStr];
        [ymStrJsonArray addObject:date];
        [jsonDict setObject:ymStrJsonArray forKey:ymStr];
    }
    else {
        NSMutableArray *ymStrJsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[date]];
        [jsonDict setObject:ymStrJsonArray forKey:ymStr];
    }
}
NSLog(@"dict  = %@", jsonDict);
```

then you convert jsonDict (NSDictionary) to json. 
I hope this code help you

Answer (score 0):

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject://pass your array here options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];